# CSS display:table-row does not expand when width is set to 100%

Tags: css

I'm having a bit of a problem. I'm using FireFox 3.6 and have the following DOM structure:

```
<div class="view-row">
    <div class="view-type">Type</div>
    <div class="view-name">Name</div>                
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.view-row {
width:100%;
display:table-row;
}

.view-name {
display: table-cell;
float:right;
}

.view-type {
display: table-cell;
}
```

If I take off the `display:table-row` it will appear correctly, with the `view-row` showing a width of 100%. If I put it back it shrinks down. I've put this up on JS Bin:

http://jsbin.com/ifiyo

What's going on?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

If you're using `display:table-row` etc., then you need proper markup, which includes a containing table. Without it your original question basically provides the equivalent bad markup of:

```
<tr style="width:100%">
    <td>Type</td>
    <td style="float:right">Name</td>
</tr>
```

Where's the table in the above? You can't just have a row out of nowhere (tr must be contained in either `table`, `thead`, `tbody`, etc.)

Instead, add an outer element with `display:table`, put the 100% width on the containing element. The two inside cells will automatically go 50/50 and align the text right on the second cell. Forget `floats` with table elements. It'll cause so many headaches.

markup:

```
<div class="view-table">
    <div class="view-row">
        <div class="view-type">Type</div>
        <div class="view-name">Name</div>                
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.view-table
{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.view-row,
{
    display:table-row;
}
.view-row > div
{
    display: table-cell;
}
.view-name 
{
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: +5 on getting rid of the damn floats!

Comment: Looks to me like you could get way with omitting the `display: table-row;` if the markup only really has one row; the `display: table-cell;` seems to infer a containing row.   
If, however, you want the appearance of another or multiple rows, then you do need the `display: table-row;`: http://jsbin.com/ifiyo/9

Comment: -1 because the explanation is just wrong. According to the [CSS2.1 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes), the markup/CSS in question is supposed to work.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Let's talk about reality and not specs. Browsers don't like table rows with no containing table. The don't handle the markup well. The solution works in real life.

Comment: No browser has any issues with the missing table (Firefox 3.0 [had](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=148810)...) The actual problem is that [width settings on table rows are entirely ignored](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#fixed-table-layout). (which means the markup/CSS in question does in fact not work as expected, so my comment above was wrong ;))

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The asker's markup is correct. As Pumbaa80 says, the issue is with assuming that the width has to be at row level instead of table level. Width is only interpreted at table level. Rows can be completely omitted. See my full answer below.

Comment: @AminAriana combined with the asker's CSS styles, the markup is only pseudo-valid. I don't care what the CSS spec says, it equates to a <tr> tag with no parent table which on its own is invalid HTML. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html#tr My answer addresses this by creating a CSS equivalent to a valid html table as per W3 guidelines. tr elements must be contained within table,thead,tfoot, or tbody. I'm suggesting the OP conform to HTML standards, even if through CSS.

Comment: @BillR you're more than welcome to downvote my "dogmatic" answer. Thanks for joining in the conversation.

Comment: I wasn't commenting on the answer which works. I was commenting on your comment that you must include a table row in CSS. You don't. To say something is pseudo valid because of you personal beliefs is a very dogmatic/rigid thing to say; Especially when the CSS was entirely valid.

Comment: guys, do you have a work around now? My question's simple, how do I display one column with full width on a row using table-cell,table-row

Comment: This answer (not any of the others) solved the problem for me

Answer (score 60):

**Tested answer:**

In the .view-row css, change:

```
display:table-row;
```

to:

```
display:table
```

and **get rid of "float"**. Everything will work as expected.

As it has been suggested in the comments, there is no need for a wrapping table. CSS allows for omitting levels of the tree structure (in this case rows) that are implicit. The reason your code doesn't work is that "width" can only be interpreted at the table level, not at the table-row level. When you have a "table" and then "table-cell"s directly underneath, they're implicitly interpreted as sitting in a row.

Working example:

```
<div class="view">
    <div>Type</div>
    <div>Name</div>                
</div>
```

with css:

```
.view {
  width:100%;
  display:table;
}

.view > div {
  width:50%;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Your answer suggests the CSS equivalent of `<table><td></td></table>` which on its own would be invalid HTML markup as per W3C. While it will validate, why would you suggest telling the browser to mimic this markup?

Comment: This is correct by CSS rules: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes . It is easier to maintain by removing unnecessary lines of code (for example, the unnecessary <view-row> div suggested by KP.). This helped me... I'm using it. +1

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to just get rid of the float statements? The .view div could keep it's display: table-row property.

Comment: It's good, ~~but doesn't work on IE9 as far as I can tell.~~ I'm wrong. It's great! :)

Comment: Of course display: table is of no use when you have more than 1 row. They all result badly unaligned

Answer (score 16):

Note that according to the CSS3 spec, you do NOT have to wrap your layout in a table-style element. The browser will infer the existence of containing elements if they do not exist.

Comment: The very same has been [specified in CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes), section 17.2.1, top 3.2. The HBOX/VBOX example below is exactly the case in question. So looks like browsers just don't care.

Answer (score 2):

give on `.view-type` class `float:left;` or delete the `float:right;` of `.view-name`

**edit:** Wrap your div `<div class="view-row">` with another div for example `<div class="table">`

and set the following css :

```
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;}
```

You have to use the table structure for correct results.

Comment: I tested with ff3.6, ie 8,chrome,opera. you can see it here http://jsbin.com/ifiyo/4 they show them side by side

Comment: I was looking to have name on the far right, type on the far left ... if you do a display:inline on both and take out the display:table-row it works, I was thinking there might be a better way to do it using the table-row/cell properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest table-cell directly within table. You muslt have a table. Starting eith table-row does not work. Try it with this HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.tr {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="table">
      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
          X
        </div>
        <div class="td">
          X
        </div>
        <div class="td">
          X
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
          X
        </div>
        <div class="td">
          X
        </div>
        <div class="td">
          X
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="table">
        <div class="td">
          X
        </div>
        <div class="td">
          X
        </div>
        <div class="td">
          X
        </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```