# div height:100%; not working with display:table-cell;

Tags: css, html

My code was working when

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px;bottom:0px; right:0px;  margin:0px;">
<div style="height:100%; width:100%; border:solid;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But not working when i added display:table-cell; to div for using vertical-align

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px;bottom:0px; right:0px;  margin:0px;">
<div style="height:100%; width:100%; border:solid; display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the div to cover the whole white space in body

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480060/css-displaytable-row-does-not-expand-when-width-is-set-to-100

Comment: Ok, what do you observe on the screen currently?

Comment: please try these codes as explaining this will waste a lot of time of both of us and there is no gaurantee that you will understand correctly what i want to say theoretically

Comment: Why you want to set the DIV display table-cell or row when the DIV is already block level element?

Comment: because i want to use vertical-align property

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code should work now.

```
<html>
<body style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px;bottom:0px; right:0px;  margin:0px;">
    <div style='display : table; width : 100%; height : 100%'>
    <div style='display : table-row;'>
        <div style="border:solid; display : table-cell;">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UuFSg/)**

---

**Rule of thumb** : Always have a proper markup whenever `display : table-cell` is concerned.

Comment: FYI, the 'table-row' <div> is not necessary

Comment: @Ashwin, Why use `display : table;` and `display : table-cell;` when you can simply use `<table><tr>` and `<td>`?

Comment: @Pacerier Because the greater web design community has decided that `table` is for displaying tabular data only. This despite the fact that **table layouts work across all browsers, old and new** and without having to resort to CSS hacks and trickery. Tables are, after all, considered harmful.

Comment: @Yuck, So tables are considered harmful for the *sake* of being considered harmful? That reminds me of the kind of answers I receive at http://stackoverflow.com/q/23453621/632951

Comment: @Pacerier I was making reference to the "goto statement considered harmful".  See also - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful

Comment: @Yuck Setting `display: table` on a non-`table` is no more a "hack" than setting `display: inline` on a non-`span` is. When the logical structure of a document differs from its presentation needs, it makes sense to use non-default display properties. This has nothing to do with whether "table layouts" are "harmful", because in both cases the layout rendering is based on exactly the same input: table display.

Comment: @Pacerier Real-world benefits of `<div>`s with `display:table` and `display:table-cell` for layout are a) they work better with responsive layouts, toggling between table-style layout on wider screens and display: block` on narrow screens, and b) are more predictable for non-visual clients like screen readers and crawlers which might otherwise read the page as if rows and columns were related

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the height to 100% for all parent elements then...

```
html, body {
    height: 100%
}
```

Give it a try, it worked for me. And better remove all the CSS properties you set to the body-element before.

Comment: it is simply not working.BTW remove this answer and get your lost reputation back

Comment: @somebodyisintrouble The solution works well. He just had to explain it properly. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Having div.table > div.table-row > table.table-cell with height of its container is a bit tricky thing. One of the easiest way is that you can add

```
.table {
    position: absolute;
}
```

in this case if you will add

```
.table {
    height: 100%;
}
```

That will fit its parent height.