# Disadvantages of using consistent-behaving yet deprecated HTML tags?

Tags: html, css, deprecated

When users visit my website, they don't care about how *perfect* or how much *standard* the page is coded. They only care about whether it works or not.

There are tags that are deprecated but have consistent behavior throughout all major, minor, and very minor browsers. They work now and [will work in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453621/disadvantages-of-using-consistent-behaving-yet-deprecated-html-tags#comment-35953529). (I'm not talking about *optional* tags like `<marquee>` and `<blink>` which will probably be removed in the future since their non-existence doesn't break pages.) The tags I'm talking about are for example:

- `<center>` (used by [google.com](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=rlZmU_ywPMHDrAeysIHABw) homepage, yes and it's May 2014)
- `<body bgcolor=`, `alink=`, `vlink=`, `link=` (all used by [google.com](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=rlZmU_ywPMHDrAeysIHABw))
- `<font size=` (also used by [google.com](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=rlZmU_ywPMHDrAeysIHABw))

If my HTML generator produces tags like `<body bgcolor=black>`, it is guaranteed to work for near 100% of users.

If it instead produce CSS like `background:black;`, it will be supported by lesser users compared to `<body bgcolor=black>`. (Start with https://superuser.com/q/732669/78897 and [https://superuser.com/q/447269/78897](https://superuser.com/questions/447269/is-there-any-way-to-view-a-webpage-without-styles-in-chrome/447276#comment-519003), though I'm sure they are [not the only ones in the whole world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability).)

Bear with me, this is a real question based on a true problem. **Exactly what are the *real* disadvantages of having these tags as output?**

Comment: I would like to know where those percentages come from

Comment: @EdHeal, You mean "aways non-zero" amount of users will be unsupported? That's from common sense.

Comment: I still use two sticks to start a fire for the exact same reason. Nevermind if the client will need to spend more time and effort every time they want to update their site and their partners see them as less professional or that they have a site they could make on their on in GeoCities, I delivered a site that "works" and got a bonus for coming in under the deadline.

Comment: @pacerier - So you are sure with 100% (not even toilet cleaner claims that). Then 0.2% - not 0.1%, 0.000000001% etc. So where do these values come from?

Comment: @Pacerier you say common sense, I say nonsense. CSS has been supported for *years* - especially basic CSS like `background-color`, `color`, etc...

Comment: @EdHeal, I've already explained. We have browsers that don't support CSS, period. **That's the truth.** Thus, the conclusion is that we have less than 100% support. U can quote *any* number, but it is still less than 100%. That's the truth.

Comment: @CollinGrady, I know that CSS has been supported for decades. But how is my above comment "nonsense"? Please explain.

Comment: What browser that is in use today doesn't support CSS?

Comment: @pacerier - there are no modern browsers that don't support CSS, that's the truth. But if your clients have users that don't support CSS, I doubt they are shocked when a page has no background color.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the merits of writing sites using "modern" vs. antiquated page styling techniques - that is, it is merely a business rule decision based on target audience.

Comment: @Anthony, You don't seem to understand the straw man fallacy. Let me repeat: The truth is that there are browsers that don't support CSS. I wasn't debating CSS support for *modern* browsers and neither should you. Also, regarding your second point: Whether the clients are shocked or not is irrelevant. What's relevant is whether the page works or not.

Comment: Hmm, a straw man argument is bad, right? Like inventing a fictional browser that can't render CSS to support your silly pompous question?

Comment: @Anthony, You have totally misunderstood what the straw man fallacy meant.

Comment: Then prove it's not a straw man; what browser that is in use by your clients doesn't support CSS?

Comment: Or even if it's technically not a straw man fallacy, prove it's a valid concern :P

Comment: @CollinGrady, A straw man fallacy meant he tries to disprove my claim by switching it to another (from "all browsers" to "modern browsers"). Gosh, do I really need to explain what a straw man fallacy means, reminds me of dealing with bairns, not to be rude, but as a matter of fact.

Comment: @CollinGrady, Do you mean "prove this is a real question with a real need"? Why don't you prove that it isn't http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presumption_of_innocence ? ;) But allow me to be kind, I shall explain: If there exist advantages of using 'consistent-behaving yet deprecated HTML tags', yet there exist no disadvantages of using them, then I would use them. Hence the question.

Comment: But your claimed advantage is nonsense and not a valid concern. Even the ease of maintenance alone is worth not using garbage like font tags.

Comment: @CollinGrady, As I've already said, it **is** a valid concern to me and it's not nonsense. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability You claim that it's nonsense, Why don't you prove that it is? I have tools to make maintaining both *equally* easy. I hope we can tackle the question instead of introducing red herrings. I would be glad if you could in fact cite some disadvantages of using them instead of questioning the premise of the question.

Comment: You've received several already and tried to throw out each and every one of them. It sounds to me more like you're trying to justify your bad decision.

Comment: And I challenge your claim that you can maintain dozens of font tags or valigns or such throughout multiple files as easily as changing a single CSS rule.

Comment: @CollinGrady, Your tendency to assume without evidence is what gives rise to this pointless argument. I would pity a country in which you hold the position of a supreme judge. And regarding your second point, You don't seem to understand the power of computers and automation. For starters, have you heard of conditional compilation?

Comment: I have all the evidence I need here in the comments and on the other answers. As for conditional compilation, I fail to see how that is in any way relevant.

Comment: I wish we all had bairns like you. Then we could all cite irrelevant rhetorical devices to *argue from authority* and avoid having genuine discourse. And a straw man argument is using a weak example (like browsers that don't support CSS ) to prove a general argument ( CSS can therefore be disregarded as necessary ). your efforts to sound educated by pointing at empty concepts undermines your argument and it's rude.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will HTML 5 validation be worth the candle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432933/will-html-5-validation-be-worth-the-candle)

Comment: @CollinGrady, If you know how conditional compilation works, you would know how automation works, and you would understand why you don't have to manually maintain those dozens of tags.

Comment: @Anthony, The whole point of this question is to have genuine discourse. **You claim** that I *argue from authority*, so exactly which one of my arguments does that? **Please be explicit.**

Comment: @Anthony, Also, a straw man argument is *not* using a weak example to prove a general case. That is called "faulty generalization". Gosh, seems like I *really* need to explain what it means. Ok, allow me to do so, A straw man argument is when one superficially distorts the claim of another. For example, when you try to tackle my claim "there exist browsers that don't support CSS" by superficially changing it to "there exist *modern* browsers that don't support CSS", it is a straw man argument because I didn't claim that "there exist *modern* browsers that don't support CSS".

Comment: @Anthony, **You claim** that I'm pointing at empty concepts, so exactly which one of my statements does it? **Please be explicit.** I have made no efforts to sound educated (although I'm flattered if you think I did). Trying to debunk my argument by how it *sounds* is a typical example of ignoratio elenchi. You claim my arguments are rude because they sound educated to you. Do I need to explain why that claim is flawed?

Answer (score 3):

Potential disadvantages include the following:

1) Your customer might actually care about how standard the code is. Maybe not now, but in the future. Maybe for questionable reasons, but still.

2) Deprecated constructs do not always work consistently. For example, `align=center` attribute set on a `table` may have different effects depending on browser mode. This is a relatively weak argument, though, since the browser practices have been described rather well in HTML5 CR and you can manage the potential problems. (Besides, even CSS settings may work inconsistently.)

3) There is no guarantee that deprecated features will be supported by all future browsers. On the other hand, the same applies to standard features. In practice, very few features that have been defined in HTML specifications have actually been removed from browsers. (Regarding tags, I think `basefont` is the only case.) All the examples mentioned, and also `marquee`, have been described in HTML5 CR as “obsolete” but still well-defined, and according to HTML5 CR, browsers are expected, and partly required, to support them all.

4) Your colleagues (designers/developers/...) may regard your code (and you) as old-fashioned, non-semantic, and whatever.

5) Code maintenance and development may be more difficult. If you have 1,000 pages with `<body bgcolor=black>` and the customer says they want a somewhat different background color, you would need to edit each page. This argument is, however, weaker than it seems to be. First, how often do such things actually happen? Second, if the pages have actually been generated using suitable tools, perhaps you just need to change the value of one parameter and regenerate them (or just let servers do that, if the pages are dynamically generated). Third, if you have a `link` element on all pages, referring to basic style sheet for the pages, as you normally should, you just need to add one rule to that style sheet. It is easy to override presentational HTML attributes with CSS.

To summarize, the practical arguments against your approach are rather weak. The most important arguments relate to coding style and principles.

Comment: **1)** No, users don't care about code. They care about what works and what doesn't. It will be hard for you to prove that users *do* care about code. **2)** You are misunderstanding consistency with identicality. When we `<center>` a content, it goes to the center regardless of the browser used. Perhaps in one browser you have one more pixel on the left, or on another you have a couple more pixels on the right. But they are consistently *centered*. This question is about tags with consistent behavior. Tags without consistent behavior are off-topic here.

Comment: **3)** That's my *exact* point, as elaborated on http://goo.gl/Flp5bH . **4)** The context of the question specifically disregards this as a *real* advantage. **5)** That's my exact point, as elaborated on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453621/disadvantages-of-using-consistent-behaving-yet-deprecated-html-tags#comment-35955096. Google doesn't hand-maintain the output of it's HTML delivered to users, neither do I. It's all, all, all generated.

Comment: **6)** The practical arguments I gave are very real. If they are not, please explain why [google.com](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=rlZmU_ywPMHDrAeysIHABw) homepage continues to serve tags like `<center>`, `<body bgcolor=`, `alink=`, `vlink=`, `link=`, `<font size=` even though it's May 2014?

Comment: What does it change that google.com uses old fashioned tags? It simple means nothing. We can find many more sites that use only modern code. We could ask ourselves - why the hell stackoverflow and sitepoint use html5 as they could still have html 4 code. What for html5 is being invented at all? All applications may be written better and worse - PHP code may also use php4 way and everything may work fine, you may insert the same piece of codes in 10 places (I used to see such "great" apps). But everything is about creating good code that could be easily maintained now and in the future.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek, The question is clear that in this context we have a specific use case to support as many browsers as possible. I'm citing Google as an example because they happen to have that kind of requirement as well. Stackoverflow and sitepoint may place their priorities on using modern tags over supporting antique browsers, but different projects have different requirements. And regarding maintainability, I've already explained in point 5 above. In short, as long as we have an engine that does the decision-making process, both options are equally maintainable.

Comment: @Pacerier It seems that you know the only acceptable answer for your question. The answer for your question (in your opinion) is "There are none" even if 99,9% of webmasters think the other way

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek, I'm only interested about facts. My opinion is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

I've added some more disadvantages:

1. Another disadvantage of using those tags is site bandwidth. When you put in html center, bgcolor and similar tags every time browser needs to load the whole content even if on every page those tags are the same or even if user visited this site many times. But when you place design in css file browsers may cache those files (especially when you set headers properly) so they only load html and images (if no cache is set).
2. One another thing is that if you decide to redesign the site/style new elements, it's much easier to put changes only in CSS files. It's possible in future you won't be doing those changes on your own or other companies/freelancers will be doing them and it will be much easier for them to make changes in the site. So the site will be cheaper to maintain.
3. In addition if html / php code is poor (or site is very complex) and many "visual conditions" appear in many files (for example on one page you decide to use one colour and you put it in HTML, on the other another colour) and something goes wrong it will be much easier to find the problem because you may simple cut some css and check where's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantage is when one of the major browsers chooses to get rid of the deprecated tag in a future release.

Comment: The question explicitly disregards tags which will be unsupported in the future...

Comment: The question can't disregard that unless you see the future, which it sounds like you don't if you're still using style attributes in 2014.

Comment: @Anthony, Have you heard of SSCCE? And back to the question, : It's clear that `<body bgcolor=black>` will be supported for as long as `<body style='background:black;'>`. Whether we can see the future or not is undebated. True, even `<body style='background:black;'>` could be unsupported in the future, even HTML5, even what comes out next year may be unsupported in the *future*. But what is clear is that tags like `<body bgcolor=black>` will be supported for as long as their current alternative (CSS) will be supported.

Comment: @Pacerier what evidence makes you think that will be supported for as long as CSS?

Comment: @CollinGrady, For knowledge of future events, we employ inductive *evidence* instead of deductive evidence. (You can see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11785062/632951#comment-35952260 if you want, but that's tangential to my point) Browsers, to remain competitive, will continue to render tags which are used as long as their alternative (not rendering it) would be relatively detrimental compared to their cost of doing so. Do you know how many millions of..................................

Comment: ............web pages exist before the introduction of CSS? So now you are the head of the Chrome team and you say "let's stop supporting bgcolor, it's uncool! It's OK to break millions of web pages, it doesn't matter one bit because being cool is more important!". Is that likely to happen? If it is, is that petition likely to succeed?

Comment: @CollinGrady, More assumptions, and now with expletives added in. It's clear from my questions that I'm trying to get real solid reasons instead of the typical *"Everyone does it this way, do it too! Don't ask so much!"*. Also, mass downvoting on my previous posts aren't going to change the facts. If `1 + 1 = 2`, it remains so regardless of how many people downvote/upvote it. If you insist `1 + 1 != 2`, please explain why, I'll be glad to hear your reasons (but it seems that you have given up, good choice though in this case).

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of using CSS over tags is that you can change the whole web site look and feel in a simple move.

Consider people that require larger font sizes. Colour blindness and also enable the most use of screen readers.

Comment: But with automation, the whole web site look and feel can be changed in a simple move as well. Consider this question coming from a HTML generator. For example, the generator has received the command to turn the background black. Should it choose `<body bgcolor=black>` or `<body style='background:black;'>`. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each option?

Comment: One HTML page, several CSS pages. CSS page delivered upon users selection. HTML content. CSS style. Very simple to implement. Leave style out of the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Even those consistent behaviour tags may be removed from browser. What if you would like to create HTML5 website? Then you will need to learn everything from scratch and change literally everything for your website to make it work because you never know if those tags will be supported in HTML 5 in future or only in older HTML documents

Comment: You are answering from the wrong angle. Re: *"What if you would like to create HTML5 website?"* Then this question don't apply.

Comment: You never know what future brings so the best option is to use code that is not deprecated at the moment of writing in my opinion.

Comment: @Pacerier it's a perfectly valid angle; do you really want to have to rewrite the entire page if the client decides one day to hop on the HTML5 bandwagon?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek, Yes we *know* that it will be supported well into the future. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453621/disadvantages-of-using-consistent-behaving-yet-deprecated-html-tags#comment-35953529

Comment: @CollinGrady, No, we don't have to rewrite them because the tags will **still work**. That's the whole point of this question.

Comment: Work? Yes. Be valid? No. So you would be selling invalid HTML5 pages.

Comment: @CollinGrady, You have missed the whole point of this question. Please re-read the first paragraph, specifically *"they don't care about how perfect or how much standard the page is coded. They only care about whether it works or not"*.

Comment: They would if they were expressly buying an HTML5 compliant page, which was Marcin's point. So take your own advice and read.

Answer (score 0):

CSS provides easier maintenance, for one; client decides they want some elements aligned left instead of center? Change your css rule and poof, you're done. But if you're using old-school valign and such? Get ready to go change every single instance of that in the file(s).

Comment: It makes no difference when we have automation in place. Want some elements aligned left instead of center? Write a single line command to the generator and it will do all the grunt work. No manual editing of files needed. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453621/disadvantages-of-using-consistent-behaving-yet-deprecated-html-tags?noredirect=1#comment-35955091