# How to make a table-row take 100% width of its container?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cd5wvr2/1/)

**Here is my code**

```css
#container {
  display: table;
  width: 600px;
}
.yellow {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.blue {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: blue;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="yellow">Chat</div>
    <div class="blue">Users</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row red">Input</div>
</div>
```

Before posting, I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480060/css-displaytable-row-does-not-expand-when-width-is-set-to-100) but this didn't help me.

How to make the `row red`  100% of the `#container` ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are forcing the `div`s to display like a `table`? The layout could achieved without doing this and would make getting the red row to fit the `width` a lot easier.

Comment: yes: it is part of a more complex table that I isolated.

Comment: If it's tabular data why not use an actual `table` (`colspan="2"` will fix all your woes) and if it's not, why not use a different method to layout your `div`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go ... and may I suggest external CSS

```css
.tbl {
  display: table;
}
.tbl .row {
  display: table-row;
}
.tbl .cell {
  display: table-cell;
} 
.tbl .chat {
  width:100px;
  background-color: yellow;
} 
.tbl .user {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width:100%
} 
.tbl .input {
  background-color: red;
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell chat">Chat</div>
    <div class="cell user">Users</div>
  </div>
  <div class="input">Input</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this given your requirement that you need to use `display:table` is :

- either using `table-layout:fixed` and `display:table-caption` with `caption-side:bottom`  (as [@LGSon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2827823/lgson) first pointed out while I was writing my answer.)

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
#container {
  display: table;
  width: 600px;
  table-layout: fixed
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.yellow {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.blue {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 600px;
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="yellow">Chat</div>
    <div class="blue">Users</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row red">Input</div>
</div>
```

- or change this to `table` markup HTML

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
#container {
  width: 600px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse:collapse
}
.yellow {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="container">
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="yellow">Chat</td>
    <td class="blue">Users</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td colspan="2" class="red">Input</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check working code below.

```css
#container {
  display:table;
  width:600px;
}
.yellow{
  display:table-cell;
  width:200px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
.blue {
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:blue;
 }
.row {
    display:table-row; 
}  
.red {
  background-color:red;
  width:600px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
    <div id="container">
     <div class="row">
           <div class="yellow">Chat</div>
            <div class="blue">Users</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row red">Input</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Op does not want to use `position:absolute`

Comment: yes: No absolute. I just want to use pure table positionning to understand. I do not understant what's wrong with my CSS for now

Answer (score -1):

please add below css

```
.row {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
} 
.yellow {
 background-color: yellow;
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
 }
.blue {
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;
 width: 70%;
}
.red {
 background-color: red;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Not good ! The goal is to use table inline, no absolute positionning. Besides it overflows the table with !

Comment: Better, but still bad, the red part now is on TOP !

Answer (score -1):

Don't use display:table-cell etc.

I give an other solution :

https://jsfiddle.net/0cd5wvr2/5/

with this css :

```
#container {
  width:600px;
}
.yellow{
  width:30%;
  background-color:yellow;
  float:left;
}
.blue {
  width:70%;
  background-color:blue;
  float:left;
 }
.red {
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Apply this css

```
#container {
  display:table;
  width:600px;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/0cd5wvr2/6/

Hope this helps you!