# Child Div Not Taking Width Of Parent

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting my "content-row" class below to take the full width of the "panel-group-item" class.

```css
.panel-group-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  border: 2px solid #73b2b2;
  margin: 10px;
}

.content-row {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: table-row;
  margin: 10px;
}

.content-row .content-row-quantity,
.content-row .content-row-remove {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 15%;
}

.content-row .content-row-pic {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  width: 17%;
}

.content-row .content-row-title {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px 8px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<li class="panel-group-item">
  <div class="content-row">
    <div class="content-row-quantity"></div>
    <div class="content-row-pic"></div>
    <div class="content-row-title"></div>
    <div class="content-row-remove "></div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: What is your `display: table`?

Comment: LOL thanks Brett, that was dumb.  Problem fixed when i added display:table and width:100%; to ".panel-group-item "

Comment: @Brett feel free to post as answer below and I can mark as correct

Comment: Consider using a table for layout if this is tabular data or flexbox instead of display: table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS display:table-row does not expand when width is set to 100%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480060/css-displaytable-row-does-not-expand-when-width-is-set-to-100)

Comment: Haha no worries....... added it as an answer :)

Comment: cheers brotha, cant believe I missed that one lmao

Comment: I've had my fair share of stupid mistakes too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because you don't have a display setting of `display: table;` on the parent element `panel-group-item`.

The table row will naturally go to 100% width of the table, but since you have no `display: table` set it's not doing that.

So I suggest doing these changes:

```
.panel-group-item {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    ......
}
```

That should do it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use display:table-row, it should be either inside a table or have an outer element with display:table.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480060/css-displaytable-row-does-not-expand-when-width-is-set-to-100), it's the same issue you are having right now I believe.

Answer (score 0):

A table-row without a table doesn't work well, so give that `.content-row` element `display: table;` and define its `width` (a table isn't 100% by default). Note the width setting `calc(100% - 20px)`, which includes the margin in the 100% width.

```css
.panel-group-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  border: 2px solid #73b2b2;
  margin: 10px;
}

.content-row {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  display: table;
  margin: 10px;
}

.content-row .content-row-quantity,
.content-row .content-row-remove {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 15%;
}

.content-row .content-row-pic {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  width: 17%;
}

.content-row .content-row-title {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px 8px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<li class="panel-group-item">
  <div class="content-row">
    <div class="content-row-quantity">1</div>
    <div class="content-row-pic">2</div>
    <div class="content-row-title">3</div>
    <div class="content-row-remove ">4</div>
  </div>
</li>
```